# Some ListViews rows unclickable

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView, each row of which has three TextViews in it. For some reason, as I scroll through the ListView, I'm not able to click on some of the rows. There doesn't seem to be any particular pattern to it. I initially thought this was a focus issue, so I added some statements to remove clickability and focus from the TextViews, but that has not resolved it. Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
questionsArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.number, questionsArrayList) {
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = convertView;

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                if (row == null) {
                    // ROW INFLATION
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questionlistitem, parent, false);
                }
                TextView number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.number);

                TextView answer = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.answer);
                TextView section = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.section);

                number.setFocusable(false);
                number.setClickable(false);

                answer.setFocusable(false);
                answer.setFocusable(false);

                section.setFocusable(false);
                section.setClickable(false);
```

Here is questionlistitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:visible="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:paddingStart="6dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" /> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:visible="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my standard listener:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    System.out.println("got clicked");

}
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Are you setting a Listener somewhere, and if not how are you determining if the rows have been clicked?  Could you post that code as well?

Comment: Done. Although I don't think the listener is the problem, since I don't see the click registering at all (the blue highlight isn't even appearing upon clicking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track in thinking that this is an issue where your `TextViews` are drawing focus away from your click events.  [I found this discussion of what may be the same problem filed as a bug report for the source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414), however this was years ago and it seems that the official word was "working as intended."  At the link, the two proposed solutions seems to be using the `android:focusable="false"` attribute on your `TextViews` in the xml (not sure if this is equivalent to doing it programmatically, as you've tried) or calling `setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);` on `convertView` before it gets returned.

Something else that may be contributing to the problem is how your `TextViews` are being arranged in your xml file.  The children of a horizontal `LinearLayout` should usually not have a `layout_width` of match_parent or fill_parent. This causes these views to expand to fill the length of the parent view, possibly overlapping their siblings and potentially causing weirdness both visually and when trying to interact with/click the children.  You may want to consider using the `layout_weight` attribute, or making the parent a `RelativeLayout`, where you'll have more control over the position of the views.

Comment: The problem ended up being in an entirely different place. Thanks anyway.